# javafx replace blocking sound with a function in a APPLICATION_MODAL stage

Tags: java, modal-dialog, javafx-2, javafx

I created a little View and put them into a stage. I set the stage APPLICATION_MODAL:

```
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

If I click on the calling Window a blocking sound appears. So this is the right action.
But is there any posibility to replace this blocking sound, with an own function? I want to close the new stage if I click on the calling window, but I really tried all what comes to my mind, even an Eventfilter for Event.ANY doesn't work:

```
    stage.addEventFilter(Event.ANY, new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            System.out.println("Event catched: "+event);
        }
    });
```

Is there any way to handle the click on the calling window?

Answer (score 1):

When you set something to `APPLICATION_MODAL`, you prevent any of the events from being dispatched to ANY window. This means that your event listener is of no use. Here is what the docs say:

> APPLICATION_MODAL
>   Defines a modal window that blocks events from being
>   delivered to any other application window.

My suggestion is that you disable all your components when your custom view is visible and when a click occurs on the parent window while your view is visible, close your view. This will solve the problem of explicitly setting the modality (Anyways your events are not being passed).

**SSCCE:**

```
package stack;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFieldBuilder;
import javafx.scene.effect.Reflection;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageBuilder;

public class DismissPopup extends Application {
    Text hello;
    Scene primaryScene;

    TextField f; 

    Stage extraStage;
    Scene extraScene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryScene = SceneBuilder
                .create()
                .width(300)
                .height(300)
                .root(new StackPane())
                .fill(Color.BLACK)
                .build();

        hello = TextBuilder
                .create()
                .text("Hello")
                .effect(new Reflection())
                .build();

        f = TextFieldBuilder
                .create()
                .promptText("Enter Some Text")
                .build();

        extraScene = SceneBuilder
                .create()
                .width(300)
                .height(300)
                .root(new StackPane())
                .fill(Color.WHEAT)
                .build();

        StackPane p = (StackPane) extraScene.getRoot();
        p.getChildren().addAll(hello);
        p = (StackPane) primaryScene.getRoot();
        p.getChildren().addAll(f);

        extraStage = StageBuilder
                    .create()
                    .scene(extraScene)
                    .build();

        extraStage.sizeToScene();

        primaryScene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                if(f.disabledProperty().get() == false){
                    f.setDisable(true);
                    f.setText("The TextField is disabled");
                    extraStage.show();
                }else{
                    f.setText("The TextField is enabled");
                    f.setDisable(false);
                    extraStage.close();
                }
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(primaryScene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch("stack.DismissPopup");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Little Child. This solution has the same effect like the version I already have. If my parent stage is in fullscreen and I show the new stage, the calling stage is send to the background, other windows on the desktop covers the calling stage and the windows taskbar appears. That`s why I asked to replace to windows-sound from the APPLICATION_MODAL stage with an own function. The question is, where is this function registered? on the calling stage? on the called stage? I have no idea :/   however, many thanks for your help!

Comment: @MutenRoshi Have you looked at `Popup` class ?

Comment: yes, but I could not find any useful methods. I also cant see anything if I create a popup,give my stage in and call show().